# How to use multiple objectfilters in python

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following object filter to get a list of virtual servers

```
object_filter1 = {
    'virtualGuests': {
    'dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag': {'operation': 1},
    'powerState': {'name': {'operation': 'Running'}}
    }

virtualServers = client['Account'].getVirtualGuests(mask=object_mask,filter=object_filter)
```

How can I define another filter with contition powerState.name == RUNNING **and** primaryIpAddress attribute having a value? (!=null) or set? I want to use both these filters applied to my result i.e. either object_filter1 condition  **or** the 2nd condition must be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the following example:

```
import SoftLayer
# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'


filterInstance = {
  'virtualGuests': {
    'powerState': {
      'name': {
        'operation': 'Running'
      }
    },
    'primaryIpAddress': {
      'operation': 'not null'
    }
  }
}

# Creates a new connection to the API service.
client = SoftLayer.Client(
    username=API_USERNAME,
    api_key=API_KEY
)

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getVirtualGuests( filter = filterInstance)
    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Failed ...  faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
        % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

**References:**

[object-filters](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)

[python::ticket_filter](https://softlayer.github.io/python/ticket_filter/)

Comment: This is working good. Just one small question if I have multiple object filters how I can use that? something like if my condition has `(condition1 or  condition2) and condition3` I know with a comma I can simualte an "and"  how can I simulate an "OR"?

Comment: This is a REST example with filters may help you: `https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"tagReferences":{"tag":{"name":{"operation":"in","options":[{"name":"data","value":["mytag","mytag2"]}]}}}}}` … where we can get `”Virtual Guests”` which contain `”mytag”` or `”mytag2”`. **Reference:** [object-filters](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters).

Comment: This will work only while comparing a common "tag". In my case I have `object_filter1 = {
    'virtualGuests': {
        'dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag': {'operation': 0},
        'powerState': {'name': {'operation': 'Running'}},
        }
}` and

`object_filter2 = {
    'virtualGuests': {
        'powerState': {'name': {'operation': 'Running'}},
        'primaryIpAddress' : {'operation': 'not null'}
        }
}
`